# Junit + Netbeans: Doesn't find methods inside class for test

Tags: java, unit-testing, netbeans, junit

I have made a very simple class to test for proper Junit test generating. The problem is that when I create a Junit test, it doesn't find my methods for some reason. I have tried with multiple very simple classes without success. I am starting to think I set up Junit for the project incorrectly. Here is my simple class I am trying to test:

```
package controller;

public class SampleProgram {

    public int multiply(int x1, int x2){
        return x1 * x2;
    }
}
```

Here is what is generated when I create a Junit Test in Netbeans:

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package controller;

import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.AfterClass;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.Test;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

public class ProgramTest {

    public ProgramTest() {
    }

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUpClass() {
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void tearDownClass() {
    }

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() {
    }

}
```

Any help as to why my method isn't being found and generating the test is much appreciated. I have not used Junit before and am completely lost. Thanks

**EDIT**
Here is a screenshot of my editor with a Junit test provided from Jose Martinez.
The imports are the defaults for when netbeans creates a Junit test.
[Screenshot](http://i1377.photobucket.com/albums/ah45/snowborder011/junit_errors_zpsc57dl52e.png)

Comment: Do you mean you do not want to add it yourself?

Comment: When you create the Test for the Class, what option are you selecting in Code Generation?

Comment: I had seen a video where the test was auto generated which I thought would be very useful for creating a skeleton for the tests, especially when I get my project rolling. EDIT: Here is what I watched https://youtu.be/Q0ue-T0Z6Zs?t=180

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to Netbeans auto unit test creator functionality then... When you right click a class in Nebeans project tab and select `Tools -> Create/Update Tests`, a dialog box will pop up.  In the Code Generation box, under Method Access Levels, select the Public radio button.

But usually this auto feature is just to get you started.  You will have to get comfortable with creating your own tests.  In this case a good unit test for multiply might look something like this.

```
@Test
public void testMultiply() {
    System.out.println("testingMultiply");

    SimpleProgram instance = new SimpleProgram();
    int expected = 12;
    int p1 = 3;
    int p2 = 4;
    int actual = instance.multiply(p1, p2);
    assertEqual(expected, actual);
}
```

Comment: I have tried your sample test case but I am still unable to run the Junit tests. I will upload a screenshot of my editor.

Answer (score 0):

You should select the correct Code Generation items from the wizard.
[image]

Comment: I selected the same options as you have provided in the screenshot.

Comment: It is very estrange.  Could you try to create some test from a new project?